# Disable laptops built-in keyboard

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, thinkpad

I have bought a new keyboard that I would like to use instead of the built-in keyboard, but I'm not able to disable the keyboard.

The "Disable" button is disabled in Device Manager, and the BIOS doesn't have an option to disable the keyboard (only pointer hardware). By uninstalling the device, Windows would just automatically install it again (right?).

Is my only option to physically unplug the keyboard? It's a bit clumsy to need a screwdriver in case I forget my external keyboard though...

I have a Lenovo X220 with Windows 7.

**EDIT:** A solution for me, but not really an answer to the question, so I'll just edit my post..

My new keyboard has small feet that fits exactly between the number and Fx row. The pressure added is not enough to push any of the buttons - problem "solved" :)

Thanks a lot to @BBlake and @Shinrai for info on the perils of unplugging the keyboard

Comment: WHY do you actually have to disable it?  How about just...not using it?

Comment: Why do you need to disable it?  An external keyboard works just fine whether the built in keyboard is working or not.

Comment: The problem is space. The keyboard is thin, so I'd like to put it on top of the laptop keyboard. But then the keyboard keeps pressing keys like "home" which makes it a bit difficult to use :)

Comment: ah, I see.  The danger with disconnecting (physically) your built in keyboard is that on many laptops, the specialized keys across the top/sides are all part of the built in keyboard and you would lose access to those keys (possibly including the power button) if the keyboard would even boot at all (which it likely won't for many laptops without the built in keyboard attached).

Comment: @BBlake: Yes, that would be a big problem. I don't think there are any special keys I don't have on the new keyboard or don't have access for through the start menu - a bit clumsier, but workable. Of course.. I might build some sort of lid over the keys, but I'm hoping for some simpler solution.

Comment: @BBlake is correct in the instance of this machine - ALL the buttons are through the keyboard connector on Thinkpads, so you wouldn't even be able to turn it on if you disconnected that.  I don't think there's any way to disable the internal keyboard, but there may be 3rd party software or something to do it.

Comment: Since you answered your own question, you should post that as an answer and accept it when possible.

Comment: It's not a real answer as it just happened to work on this keyboard. I'll let someone else answer if they know how.